# Easy way to crush beans / peanuts?

Tags: food, substitute-tool, kitchen

I am looking for an easy way to crush beans like mongo and black beans, also peanuts. Obviously I can use blender right? But are there any other tools or methods that I can use to crush those kind of foods in an *easy* and *practical* way?

**Note:** By saying easy and practical way I am looking for tools that can be easily found in houses or kitchens.

Answer (score 4):

Besides from the blender you already mentioned, you can put the peanuts onto a dishcloth and then take the edges and fold it so the nuts can't fall out. Then you just take a hammer or something similar and hit the peanuts inside the dishcloth until they have the size you want them to. For the beans you could use a plastic bag as well and probably shouldn't hit as hard as with the peanuts. Works also great, if you want to get rid of any kind of aggression.

Don't know what you mean with mongo though.

Answer (score 1):

You could put the beans in a large bag and spread them out on a table surface.

You could then either use somethign such as :

- rolling pin to roll over them
- wooden breadboard and lean your weight on it

Ensure you leave enough 'bag space' so that the bag doesn't burst as you squash the beans

Answer (score 0):

If you have cooked beans, a fork and bowl will do the job.

A Mortar and Pestle could work for something harder like peanuts, or dry beans. The Mortar usually a heavy stone or ceramic bowl (or vessel - they can be large) and the pestle is a heavy club shaped tool used to mash the contents of the mortar.

Answer (score 0):

What is the end goal of crushing these beans / nuts? If you're looking for a "paste", then I suggest a food processor.

If you are looking to just chop a small quantity, you could use an electric coffee grinder for all sorts of seeds, nuts, and herbs,  like so:
[image: coffee grinder]
<sub>(source: [tlbox.com](http://www.tlbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/Coffee-Grinder.jpg))</sub>
See: [if I put peanuts in a coffee grinder will I get powder or paste?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/42641/if-i-put-peanuts-in-a-coffee-grinder-will-i-get-peanut-butter-or-peanut-powder)

Ultimately, if you're dealing with more than a couple hundred grams of beans/nuts, you'll want a food-processor. It will do the job really well, and allow you to even make a butter/paste.

Comment: This red Bosch chopper is not at all hand powered, as per its description, it has a "Powerful motor with 400 watt". Also, my mom has this model (although in white) and it does need to be connected to an outlet.

Comment: Great point, I suppose I was thinking of another item.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are not looking for paste but just little bit grinding,In this process no tools required,

just wrap them up in a cloth that won't tear up, now smash that cloth against slab or floor, press them with both hands after this.

(also if it does not matter For further grinding you can use your foots,but many people don't like touching foot to eatable things.)